# Load date from R date frame into Oracle database

Tags: r, oracle, dbi

I am writing a data.frame through odbc into oracle database. The oracle table consist of 2 columns - Date_Updated and Count_type (varchar). When I execute the dbWriteTable, it gives me a conversion error stating “Invalid character value for cast specification.” I know this is referring to date field because the load works fine when I convert the Oracle date field data type as varchar, the data gets loaded.

```r
#Loading command line
dbWriteTable(conn, “Oracle_Table_Name”, df, append = TRUE)
```

I am initially pulling the Date_Updated field from oracle database that is defined as Date data type and then loading back into new oracle table.

Any suggestion on how I can write back the data with date format type into oracle database.

Here it is from dput - structure(list(Date_updated = structure(c(“22-May-2023”, “22-May-2023”), class = “AsIs”), count_type = structure (c(1L, 1L) .Label = “Pass”, class = “factor”)

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data: `dput(head(df))` (please [edit] your question and paste that inside of a [code block], thanks!)

Comment: Do you already have an existing table you are adding to? You may want to confirm that the column type of the existing data is Date and not varchar2.

Comment: Here it is from dput - structure(list(Date_updated = structure(c(“22-May-2023”, “22-May-2023”), class = “AsIs”), count_type = structure (c(1L, 1L) .Label = “Pass”, class = “factor”)

Comment: Hi Dave, yea I have an existing table with column type date. However as I said above, the load fails. But when I change the existing table column type as varchar, the data gets loaded.

Comment: I don't have access to Oracle, but perhaps it does not automatically parse `"22-May-2023"` as a date; to be clear, to R this is just a string. Consider converting your column to _real dates_ (`Date`-class) instead of strings, ala `as.Date(df$Date_updated, format="%d-%b-%Y")`. **However** ... your `dput` is incomplete, so we can't use that, **and** why is `Date_updated` classes as `"AsIs"`? Either way, that breaks a lot more things, you may need `as.Date(unclass(df$Date_updated), format="%d-%b-%Y")` (assigned back to your frame) before inserting.

Comment: Thanks. Yep it needed that conversion and now able to load in oracle table as a date field.